# Microphone and Google Hangouts

Tags: google-chrome, microphone, google-hangouts

Using Kubuntu 16.04, I'm trying to use Google Hangouts via Chrome. Webcam works fine, however no one can hear me.

Using Blue's Snowball which works fine in Skype and Audacity.

Someone suggested I need to disable the linein, not sure how to do that.

Any help would be much appreciated.